# How to print out statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to get the function to print statements that fall in line with code but it is saying that some numbers that are not represented are printing out the size instead of N/A

I have used || or and &&

```js
var shirtWidth = 23;
    var shirtLength = 30;
    var shirtSleeve = 8.71;
    
    // Write your if/else code here

    if (shirtWidth===18 || shirtWidth <20 && shirtLength===28 || shirtLength < 29 && shirtSleeve===8.13 || shirtSleeve <8.38 ){
    
    console.log("S");
    
    }else if (shirtWidth===20 || shirtWidth<22 && shirtLength===29 || shirtLength <30  && shirtSleeve===8.38 || shirtSleeve <8.63){
    
    console.log("M");
    
    }else if (shirtWidth===22 || shirtWidth <24 && shirtLength===30 || shirtLength <31 && shirtSleeve===8.63 || shirtSleeve < 8.88){
    
    console.log("L");
    
    }else if (shirtWidth===24 || shirtWidth <26 && shirtLength===31 || shirtLength < 33 && shirtSleeve===8.88 || shirtSleeve < 9.63){
    
    console.log("XL");
    
    }else if (shirtWidth===26 || shirtWidth < 28 && shirtLength===33 || shirtLength<34 && shirtSleeve===9.63 || shirtSleeve < 10.13){
    
    console.log("2XL");
    
    }else if (shirtWidth===28 && shirtLength===34 && shirtSleeve===10.13){
    
    console.log("3XL");
    
    }else{
    
    console.log("N/A");
    
    }
```

Expected shirtWidth of 18, shirtLength of 29, and shirtSleeve of 8.47 to log the size N/A, but received S

Comment: && has a higher precedence than ||. You might be better to use brackets.

e..g is 2 + 3 x 5 = 17 or 25?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: *it is saying that some numbers that are not represented*   Please post exact error messages, this is a great troubleshooting aid and helps us better understand your problem.

Comment: You need to put proper conditions with `()`, For example `if( ( 10 === 10 || 10 < (10 - 1) ) && ( typeof 10 === 'number' && (10 > 0)) )`

Answer (score 1):

When using an OR operator e.g. `a===1 || b===1`, the condition true when one of the two is true.

So when you say:

```
if (shirtWidth === 18 || ...) {
  console.log("S");
}
```

all your code behind the `||` will not be looked at when shirtWidth = 18.

Also keep in mind the precedence of `&&` and `||`, it can be useful to place brackets even if they are not necessary:

```
if (shirtWidth===18 
    || (shirtWidth < 20 && shirtLength === 28)
    || (shirtLength < 29 && shirtSleeve === 8.13)
    || shirtSleeve < 8.38)
```